# Handle arrow keys in KeyDown event of FlipView

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am using a FlipView in my Windows Store application which displays a list of items. The FlipView should flip its items on the horizontal axis (which works). Also, the items are in a ScrollViewer and often higher than the Height of the display, so there is a Vertical scrollbar.

I want the user to be able to use the up/down arrow keys to scroll, but use left and right arrow keys to flip.

Right now, all arrow keys trigger the flip.

I have tried numerous things, using Behaviors, registering to KeyDown events, but the arrow Keys are not triggering the KeyDown event.

I have also tried registering at the CoreWindow.KeyDown event, but the events arrive there already Handled, so i cannot do anything to prevent the flipview from flipping.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I know it's very very late but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33254742/231837) might be the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not going to be able to use the standard key events.

Try This: In your XAML, place a Grid after the FlipView. So you would have

```
<FlipView>...</FlipView>
<Grid KeyUp="grid_KeyUp" />
```

In this event, if you can capture it, set the event to handled so it doesn't bubble to the FlipView. You can then manually navigate the flipview with this event handler (or scroll it) by handling the appropriate keys.

Comment: Unfortunatly that does not work, i am not getting the KeyDown events. FlipView just eats up everything.

Comment: When it loads, focus the grid with the Keyboard focus type (also try Programmatic).

Comment: I checked, but looks like you cant focus a Grid?

Comment: Strange, maybe not since it takes no input. Just use a textbox then and make it small (or set height and width to 0). When the page loads just focus that and handle the keys

Comment: I tried what you suggested and i was able to get the events but it also rendered the FlipView unusable with mouse. Since it never gets the focus (as soon as it gets it, you cant handle it anywhere else anymore) there is no scrollbar and no flip buttons for the user to click on. I really just want to disable the handling of the vertical direction inputs OR want the flipview to realize there is a scrollviewer inside and pass the events to it.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately Microsoft didn't design it for this. That is strange that it rendered the FlipView unusable with a mouse. Why would that happen? What else did you add to your code? In the textbox keyup event, if the arrow key is up or down just manually increase/decrease the offset of the scrollviewer. That is all you need to do. When the FlipView's item changes, set the focus back to the textbox. If the right or left arrow key is pressed, navigate the FlipView. Also set e.handled to true.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21331/discussion-between-urbanesc-and-caleb-keith)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the FlipViewItems behaviour by setting it's IsTabStop property to false;

```
 <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="FlipViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <FlipView x:Name="FlippOut">
    ...
```

This will implicitly set the style of the FlipViewItem to not be a tabstop. That way, your scrollviewer will get all the tab-stops. You can then use AddHandler on the ScrollViewer to capture its KeyDown events and if it's left or right, flip the flipview.

A word of warning though, changing this property on the FlipViewItem does seem to make the FlipView flicker in certain scenarios, such as when you manually set the SelectedIndex to something (not sure if it'll be a problem in this case or not). I just posted about the flickering in the MSDN forums, still awaiting a reply to see if it's a bug on their end or something else: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/ffd5fe5d-de6e-4f22-82b7-e7cd82d488ad

It might be worth a try.