# Disable left/right/up/down hotkeys in flipview

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, flipview

How to disable right/left/up/down arrows hotkeys in flipview? I have a textbox on a flipview and when I move cursor using keyboard arrows and reach the end of textbox, it doesn't stop but flips the page which is annoying and is not applicable for my case. The same is true for cursor reaching the beginning of the textbox. I've tried different solutions, but none of them work.

```
<FlipView x:Name="flipView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False">            
        <FlipView.Items>
            <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Text="AAAAA1"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="AAAAA2"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Text="BBBBB1"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Text="BBBBB2"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Text="CCCCC1"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Text="CCCCC2"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </FlipView.Items>
        </FlipView>
```

Comment: Not exactly the same question but the [same solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558920/preventing-default-behaviour-of-returnenter-up-and-down-arrow-keys-for-a-list/32628253#32628253) applies to this I guess.

Comment: @JustinXL Beleive it or not, but I've tried this solution before asking question (I've tried different approaches) and this event is not fired during page flipping with arrows. This control turns out to be really weird. It's not that easy-peasy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to handle `KeyDown` inside a *custom* `FlipViewItem` instead of `FlipView` itself.

So, you will first need to extend both classes.

```
public sealed class CustomFlipView : FlipView
{
    public CustomFlipView()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomFlipView);
    }

    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new CustomFlipViewItem();
    }
}

public sealed class CustomFlipViewItem : FlipViewItem
{
    public CustomFlipViewItem()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomFlipViewItem);
    }


    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Left || e.Key == VirtualKey.Right || e.Key == VirtualKey.Up || e.Key == VirtualKey.Down)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to copy the default styles to *Themes > Generic.xaml*.

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomFlipViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomFlipViewItem">
                <ContentPresenter BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="local:CustomFlipView">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundListLowBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel AreScrollSnapPointsRegular="True" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomFlipView">
                <Grid BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalNextTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                            <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltMediumHighBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E3;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MirroredWhenRightToLeft="True" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalPreviousTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                            <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltMediumHighBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E2;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MirroredWhenRightToLeft="True" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalNextTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                            <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltMediumHighBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E5;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalPreviousTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                            <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource FlipViewButtonBorderThemeThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAltMediumHighBrush}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltMediumHighBrush}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E4;" HorizontalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollingHost" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" VerticalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                    <Button x:Name="PreviousButtonHorizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource HorizontalPreviousTemplate}" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20" />
                    <Button x:Name="NextButtonHorizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="36" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource HorizontalNextTemplate}" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20" />
                    <Button x:Name="PreviousButtonVertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource VerticalPreviousTemplate}" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" />
                    <Button x:Name="NextButtonVertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource VerticalNextTemplate}" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="36" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here's a [working demo](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/CustomFlipViewDemo). :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix it is to filter them in KeyDown event of the each stackpanel.